# Can't assign function call while changng a variable

Tags: python, python-2.x

I was checking a project that i have to turn in (it's a battleship game) and for some reason when it runs "through" the section bellow it says "can't assign function call" when it's a copy paste of a piece of just above (with a couple changes) and it gives no error. Do you see the error?

```
    '''
     elif y == "v":
            if a + 3 > 4:
                return "put the boat higher, here it leaves the board"
            else:
                board(a)(b) = "V"
                a = a + 1
                board(a)(b) = "V"
                a = a + 1
                board(a)(b) = "V"
                return board        

    '''
```

Comment: `board(a)(b) = "V"` should probably be `board[a][b] = "V"`, if you're accessing elements of a data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend you to use python 3, [read this](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

And I don't know what is `board`, so I will answer for two cases.

1. `board` is not a function, nested python list
   In this case, just change `()` to `[]` to access array.
2. `board` is a function
   In this case, you're definitely wrong. board() is a function call and will return function result. So, you cannot assign "V" into your function call. This is pretty natural.

Now, check out what is your case and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of accessing a matrix with the `[]` operator you are making calls with `()`. So try replacing `board(a)(b)` with `board[a][b]` but without more information is really hard to tell.

Comment: @PauFrancoToda no problem man, if it solves your problem consider select it as the accepted answer.